# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "comments" at path "_id" for model "post"

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Comments is an array nested inside Post Schema. I want to update corresponding post by push a new comment to the comments array. But got the error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "comments" at path "_id" for model "post"

1. Read related posts
2. Tried to use "mongoose.Types.ObjectId", didn't work
3. Mongoose version ^5.5.4
4. All the ID I am using here are valid

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    comments: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user',
            },
            body: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, 'Content required'],
            },
        }
    ],
   ...
});
```

```
PostRouter.put('/posts/comments', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.query;
    const userID = req.body.user;
    const body = req.body.body;
    const comment = {
        user: userID,
        body: body,
    };

    Posts
        .update({ _id: id }, { $push: { comments: comment }})
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json(result.ok);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

I have a similar one: add a "friendID" to User Modal "friends" array. works as expected.

```
const senderID = req.query.sender;
const recipientID = req.query.recipient; 

Users .update({ _id: recipientID }, { $push: { friends: senderID }}) 
.then(result => res.status(200).json(result.ok)) 
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

but the "comment" I try to add here is an object instead of a valid ID string.

I think the problem is inside "Comments" array, because "comment.user" is ref from my "User" Schema. Don't know how to solve this nested question with cast error.

Answer (score 1):

**mongoose.Types.ObjectId** is redundant if userID and _id are valid mongodb _id.

```
PostRouter.put('/posts/comments', (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.query;
const userID = req.body.user;
const body = req.body.body;
const comment = {
    user: userID,
    body: body,
};

Posts
    .update({ _id: id }, { $push: { comments: comment }})
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json(result.ok);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: This is my original code, but didn't work, got the cast err. Then I read some posts and added the "mongoose.Types.ObjectId", like the code above, but still doesn't work, still cast the same err.

Comment: Found the problem: I had another "put" method with path "/:id". This one's path is "/comments". After remove the first put method, my code works.